# Copy of Existing Table Daily to Track Changes

Tags: sql, t-sql

I had a one table called DEALER_DETAILED in my customer database.In that table STATUS columns indicates 3 paramaters like as, OPERATIONAL,DEACTIVE,NON-OPERATIONAL.

Every night between 3-6 oclock, one of the parameter may change. For example today one of DEALER_CODE status is operational but after tomorrow that DEALER_CODE status will be DEACTIVE. I don't wanna use trigger that is why,using with stored procedure I need to get a copy of that table daily and write another queries to track changes.

For copy and track changes I wrote the queries as below but at the present it does not work.I mean I could not able to track the changes right now.

This is what I written. Could you please help me is there any fault on that code ?

```
> ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_CreateDealertTable]  AS
> 
> BEGIN
> 
> SET NOCOUNT ON;
> 
> IF EXISTS (SELECT *
>                            FROM   sys.objects
>                            WHERE  object_id = Object_id(N'[dbo].[Dealer_Detailed_old]')
>                                           AND TYPE IN ( N'U' ))
>                 DROP TABLE [dbo].[Dealer_Detailed_old];
> 
>    PRINT 'Creating table [dbo].[Dealer_Detailed_old].';
> 
>    CREATE TABLE dbo.Dealer_Detailed_old ( [DealerCode]
> nvarchar(32),[DealerName] nvarchar(max),[Status] nvarchar(20))
>       
>        INSERT INTO Dealer_Detailed_old
>             SELECT DEALER_CODE,DEALER_NAME,[STATUS] FROM dbo.DEALER_DETAILED
>             
>       END

step 2---track changes

      IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#tempstatus') IS NOT NULL
drop table #tempstatus

      SELECT * INTO #tempstatus FROM
      (
            SELECT 
                  old.DealerCode as DEALERCODE, old.[Status] as STATUSOLD ,new.[STATUS] AS STATUSNEW
            FROM 
                   [dbo].[Dealer_Detailed_old] as old
            INNER JOIN
                  [dbo].[DEALER_DETAILED] as new ON old.DealerCode = new.DEALER_CODE
            WHERE 
            old.[Status] <> new.[STATUS]
            ) as tbl2


IF (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM #tempstatus)> 0
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't quite get why you always drop your tables, but okay.

To track changes on a table, I usually do it like this (example):

Table1: Cars (ID,Color,Name)
Table2: Cars_log (ID, CarID, Color, Name, Changed_at)

Whenever you insert something in the Cars-Table, insert it into the Cars_log table aswell, including the time of the change(Changed_at = NOW()).

Comment: Actually we are creating this table via web-service that we take from our customer. This is not our table.Everyday the status column might be change and therefore we need to track this changes.